# Subtrair data vinda de input com data atual

Tags: javascript, data

Estou tentando subtrair uma data que o usuário digita no input com a data atual.

```
 var data1 = $("#data_viagem").val();
 var data1 = data1.split("/");
 var viagem = new Date(data1[2], data1[1], data1[0]);

 var dateObj = new Date();
 var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
 var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
 var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
```

Montei esses dois blocos para montar as duas datas, mas não consigo passar daqui. Não estou conseguindo montar a data atual para fazer uma subtração válida. Recebo resultados errados.

Comment: Você quer calcular a diferença?!

Comment: Isso. A diferença em dias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja abaixo uma forma fácil para calcular diferença usando o [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) com os métodos `abs()` e `ceil()`.

- `Math.abs(x)` : retorna o valor absoluto de `x`, no qual é calculado a diferença das datas usando o método `getTime`.
- `Math.ceil(x)`: retorna o menor número inteiro maior ou igual a `x`.

```js
var date1 = new Date("05/05/2017");
var date2 = new Date("08/17/2017");

var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays+ " dias");
```

Adaptando ao seu caso, resgatando a data atual usando `Date`, ficaria algo assim:

```js
var dataAtual = new Date();
var dd = dataAtual.getDate();
var mm = dataAtual.getMonth()+1; //Janeiro é 0!
var yyyy = dataAtual.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

dataAtual = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
console.log(dataAtual);

var date1 = new Date("05/05/2017");
var date2 = new Date(dataAtual);

var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays+ " dias");
```

Se preferir também, podes usar o plugin [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/). Veja como pode ser fácil:

```js
var viagem = moment("05/05/2017", "MM/DD/YYYY");
var dataAtual = moment(moment(), "MM/DD/YYYY");
var diffDays = dataAtual.diff(viagem, 'days');

console.log(diffDays+" dias");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>

<div id='result'></div>
```